# I nput type date display always JJ/MM/year

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a date saved insde my db but If I use this synthax the date not appear (`<input type="date" name="customers_dob" value="14/05/2019" class="form-control">`).

```
echo HTML::inputField('birth', $date_dob, null, 'date');
```

My field appear always with this element : `JJ/MM/AA` and I don't see the value.

Comment: How are you retrieving the data from the database?

Comment: @ThisBoyPerforms :  $date_dob = DateTime::toShort($cInfo->customers_dob);